expected dwell time
I am trying to calculate the dwell time of a mobile user in a UAV coverage. So if \$x_\text{start}\$ and \$y_\text{start}\$ are the initial positions and \$x_\text{end}\$ and \$y_\text{end}\$ are the final positions and the distance between them i-e
$$
 d=\sqrt{ (x_\text{start}-x_\text{end})^2 +(y_\text{start}-y_\text{end})^2}
$$
here if I assume that the speed v is constant the dwell time is given as \$t_\text{dwell}= d/v\$.
Question. Said that, is the following approach to the calculation of the expected dwell time correct?

Define the distribution of end points as bivariate normal distribution
Set up the integral
$$
\mathbb{E}[d] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \sqrt{(x_{\text{start}} - x_{\text{end}})^2 + (y_{\text{start}} - y_{\text{end}})^2} \, f_{X,Y}(x_{\text{end}}, y_{\text{end}}) \, dx_{\text{end}} \, dy_{\text{end}}
$$
where
\$f_{X,Y}(x_{\text{end}}, y_{\text{end}})\$ is the joint probability density function of the end positions.



define the distribution of end points as bivariate normal distribution

I agree, communications engineering loves their normal distributions. But: does it seem to make sense to you to assume mobile users "appear" in a Gaussian cluster?
In most ad-hoc network models I'm aware of, the assumption is rather that the location of users is a uniform Poisson point process, where the probability that a user is in any region of the "map" is proportional to the area of that region, and irrespective of the location of the region relative to some arbitrarily chosen coordinate axis.
Makes sense to me, both mathematically that is easier to handle, and it represents the reality quite well that humans aren't very prone to flogging circularly around some central people-magnet.
Similarly, I'd assume start and end points to follow a PPP.
You might want to do whatever you want to calculate, and add another constraint, if it makes things easier: You could assume a user always passes completely through the area of coverage. Especially if that area is a circle, that simplifies your calculations to a 1D density: How far off-center will the line cross (and thus, how long is the intersection of line and circular area)? Again, this might be harder, or it might make things simpler.

Set up the integral \$\mathbb{E}[d] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \sqrt{(x_{\text{start}} - x_{\text{end}})^2 + (y_{\text{start}} - y_{\text{end}})^2} \, f_{X,Y}(x_{\text{end}}, y_{\text{end}}) \, dx_{\text{end}} \, dy_{\text{end}}\$

That \$f_{X,Y}\$ would be a constant for a PPP. Much nicer to calculate, isn't it?

Not to poach people away from this site, but since you have [tag:signal-theory] among your tags: don't shy away of asking further questions on https://signals.stackexchange.com , our signal processing sister site. Don't forget to link to your question here if it's related, and avoid posting the same question to multiple sites, please :)
